# OUTDATED: Updating a UILabel to display current location

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

**TLDR;**

I want to get locations outside the main thread using a different function but I am receiving delays.

**In details:**

I'm performing a GET request. later on I parse the JSON to get the current locaction in a method called 'locationManager'
now I have a UILabel outlet that I want to update all the time to the current location displayed on the map according to the result of the JSON (does reverse geocode) but if I access the label.text through the locationManager I have a delay + Xcode tells me that it should only be done through the main thread.

so I've tried making a global variable and updating it in the locationManager but then when I access the label.text in viewDidLoad() and feed it the global variable it stays empty (initial value)

what could be a possible fix to this?

```
var addrs = "" // the global variable 

...

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //Code
     addrs = result.response.view[0].result[0].location.address.label
    } .resume()
    

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  locationLabel.text = ("Your Current Location Is :" + addrs)
}
```

Comment: so i use it in super.viewDidLoad() and it stays the empty string

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async { /* WRITE CODE HERE */
        
    }`

Comment: but what do i write inside ?  should i just move my entire locationManager function into it? @dahiya_boy

Comment: update your label in `locationManager` inside the block I posted above. Its the main thread. **NOTE** All the UI updates should be done in main thread.

Comment: @dahiya_boy thank you thank you thank youuu !! it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Always update your UI's only on the main thread. Use below code to resolve your issue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    addrs = result.response.view[0].result[0].location.address.label
    self?.locationLabel.text = ("Your Current Location Is :" + addrs)
}
```